# How do I remove Bootstrap from asp.net project?

Tags: css, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I created an ASP.Net webforms project and after doing all the backend stuff, I now want to work on the design. I want to use Google Material Design Lite.  The project currently has all the Bootstrap styles that it puts in when I created the project and I want to remove all of that.  I removed all of the stylesheet files I could find, and yet the appearance of the site remains the same.
Where is it getting the stylesheet information from if not from *.css files and how do I get rid of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to remove the masterpage and import your own stuff. Create a webpage without using a masterpage. And then import your own CSS.

Comment: Will I have to build my own master page? Is there not just bits I can comment out?

Comment: Even though the Content/css is actually empty, I commented out this line and it has removed the styling. Just hope I can replace it.

<webopt:BundleReference runat="server" Path="~/Content/css" />

Comment: It works like HTML you just import them in every page. Or you can create your own masterpage but that's not needed though.